# How to create an Xpath for a checkbox?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, xpath

I've tried the following xpath but none of them work. The id is listed differently everytime. Next to the checkbox is this word " poetin alfa"

```
- //input[@type='checkbox'][@value='on']
- //*[@id='id1']
-//input[contains(text(),'<poetin alfa>')]/preceding-sibling::input[@type='checkbox']
- //input[contains(text(),'<poetin alfa>')]/following-sibling::input[@type='checkbox']



<span class="v-checkbox v-widget">
<input id="id1" type="checkbox" value="on" tabindex="0"/>
<label for="id1"/>
```

Comment: Where is that word in your example html?

Comment: `<poetin alfa>` are an other checkbox value ? Another tag with "poaetin alpha" as text ? In your XPath example, you seem to be looking for a tag into a text of another tag.
Please provide full example of your HTML which containing the `poetin alfa` tag, it will be easier to help you

Comment: Please provide more info

Comment: Are your <span>, <input> and <label> all nested one inside the other? Please show more of your HTML.

Comment: The id alone should work since it's supposed to be unique, but I suspect that the HTML code you think is shown is not what is actually shown.  You're searching for text in a label that does not appear to be in the label tag.  I would think a proper label would be `<label for="id1">poetin alfa</label>` or if it really does have ankle brackets `<label for="id1">&lt;poetin alfa&gt;</label>`

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below xpath.

```
//input[contains(text(),'poetin alfa')]/preceding-sibling::input[@type='checkbox']
```

As you didnt provide the html structure of the text (poetin alfa), I will go with your xpath. 
The xpath which you constructed has <>.

//input[contains(text(),'')]

You should remove the <> in contains text().